# how to .createEmptyMovieClip inside another dynamically created MovieClip? (AS2)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, movieclip

I'm trying to create a movieclip and load a "frame" image inside of it, then create another movieclip inside of the first, and then load another picture inside of the second. Something like this:

```
var thumbFrame;
var thumbPicture;

thumbFrame = container_mc.createEmptyMovieClip(thumbFrameName, 1);
thumbFrame.loadMovie("thumbFrame.png");
thumbFrame._x = 0;
thumbFrame._y = 0;

thumbPicture = thumbFrame.createEmptyMovieClip(thumbPictureName, 2);
thumbPicture.loadMovie("thumbPicture.jpg");
thumbPicture._x = 0;
thumbPicture._y = 0;
```

But it doesn't seem to work the way I want: the "thumbPicture" doesn't appear on top of the "thumbFrame" as I expected... only the "thumbFrame" shows (with it's image succesfully loaded). Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** If I comment this:

```
//thumbFrame.loadMovie("thumbFrame.png");
```

The thumbPicture.jpg shows inside of the first movieclip, so maybe the issue is with the .loadMovie?

Comment: I haven't done any as2 in ages and can't test at the moment. As far as I remember loadMovie loaded content on 'levels' (e.g. _level0,_level1, etc.), I might be wrong. I think it will be more predictable/reliable to use the MovieClipLoader using the [loadClip()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001381.html) method. You can also check for errors/content initialized(get content size, etc.). Try this: 2 empty movie clips inside container_mc that you load content into using MovieClipLoader's loadClip().

Answer (score 0):

put your code into a function:

```
var thumbFrame;
var thumbPicture;

function loadClip1(){
thumbFrame = container_mc.createEmptyMovieClip(thumbFrameName, 1);
thumbFrame.loadMovie("thumbFrame.png");
thumbFrame._x = 0;
thumbFrame._y = 0;
}
```

now create another function for an oncomplete method to instruct to create your other movieClip inside the 1st clip.

whats happening you have to create 1 empty movieclip first, then create the next movieclip after this one is created inside of it.